# Density plot with epanechnikov with exceedance data

Tags: nonparametric, density-function, kernel-smoothing, extreme-value, nonparametric-density

I'm trying to replicate empirical density plot from the paper "[Computing Maximum Likelihood Estimates for the Generalized Pareto Distribution](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1269663?seq=1)".

The data is `Exceedance (in kg/mm2) of the Testing Threshold in Tensile-Strength Tests for a Random Sample of n = 15 Nylon Carpet Fibers`. Below is the density estimate using Epanechnikov kernel. The paper is about generalized pareto distribution using exceedance data, related to extreme value theory.

[image]

I tried to replicate/reproducing this figure in `R` using `density`, but unable to do this, see below for reproducible example based on the data in the paper.

```
tensile_strength <- (0.051,0.140,0.365,0.561,0.030,0.268,0.184,0.1,0.876,0.092,0.011,0.2,0.518,0.338,0.056)
          
plot(density(tensile_strength, bw=0.18, kernel=c("epanechnikov"),from=0.01, to=1)) 
lines(x=tensile_strength,y=rep(0,length(ans)),type="p")
```

Here is the density plot.

[image]

The plot is nowhere close to what is in the article.

My question is how does one account for "Epanechnikov kernel **with boundary kernel modifications** (since the exceedances must be greater than 0)"

Comment: Uff... messy. (+1). It relates to the fact that as we go closer to the boundaries the weights of the kernel window falling outside the support are set to 0 and the remaining non-zero weights (i.e. the one still in the support) are upscaled such that they sum up to 1. Quite common for all kernel regression approaches actually; e.g. see the Wikipedia article on [Kernel regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression) and notice the normalisation in the Nadaraya-Watson estimator's denominator.

Comment: @usεr11852 thanks, your comment helped me solve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to follow @usεr11852 comments and was able to reproduce from the original paper. For truncated/bounded data one would have to used bounded density estimation.

Below is the code to reproduce the plots from the paper.

```
library(bde)

## Data
tensile_strength <- c(0.051,0.140,0.365,0.561,0.030,0.268,0.184,0.1,0.876,0.092,0.011,0.2,0.518,0.338,0.056)

## Density plots with bounded data
 plot(bde(tensile_strength,estimator="boundarykernel",lower.limit = 0,upper.limit = 1,options = list(mu=1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Sweet! Thank you for sharing. (+1)

Comment: You are correct let me fix it.

Comment: Thansk for pointing it out @usεr11852 I have fixed the answer.